# WordPress: Remove name & Public name registration fields

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any possibility to remove unnecessary fields in the wordpress standard registration process like the name, last name and public name fields? There are just more stepts for users that nobody needs. Normally these fields are required in the registration.

Just the username and the email field are sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this in wordpress...

You just need to edit the templates...

OR

change the hooks.-

Answer (score 0):

**Absolutely YES, you can achieve this.**

Rule 1: WordPress requires a username. We must provide a username.

Rule 2: Don't edit WordPress core code.

We can achieve this by hiding username field, get email and store it as username.

Step-1: Remove Username textfield

```
add_action('login_head', function(){
?>
    <style>
        #registerform > p:first-child{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#registerform > p:first-child').css('display', 'none');
        });
    </script>
<?php
});
```

**Step-2: Remove Username error**

```
//Remove error for username, only show error for email only.
add_filter('registration_errors', function($wp_error, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email){
    if(isset($wp_error->errors['empty_username'])){
        unset($wp_error->errors['empty_username']);
    }

    if(isset($wp_error->errors['username_exists'])){
        unset($wp_error->errors['username_exists']);
    }
    return $wp_error;
}, 10, 3);
```

**Step-3: Manipulate Background Registration Functionality.**

```
add_action('login_form_register', function(){
    if(isset($_POST['user_login']) && isset($_POST['user_email']) && !empty($_POST['user_email'])){
        $_POST['user_login'] = $_POST['user_email'];
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! But what is with the fields Name, last name and public name? These fields are also not required for me.

Comment: Just use this example above ... you will understand what you need to do...

Comment: Where can I find the error-names of the other fields like first name?